# Two dimensional random vector of mixed coordinates

Tags: probability-theory

I am looking for a real life example of two dimentional random vector of mixed types: one of its coordinate is discret random variable and the other is continous. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Consider a population of people represented by a two element vector.  The first element is 0 if the person is male and 1 if the person is female.  The second element is their age (in seconds).

Select any vector at random, and you have what you've asked for.